# There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first

Tags: android, android-studio

I have ADT Eclipse Project and I want to just import that project in android studio.

But I got this error There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first.

[image: This is screenshot of Error]

Comment: Please read the information displaying in the window, this is generally due to the library project path , which is not present on the path what android studio has resolved.
Please remove the alert window and post the detail on import info window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is saying that your project depends on google_Play_Service_Lib and android studio is not able to find that dependency, but what android studio did is giving you the path where you can paste that library and then you will able to import that project.

first download google_service_lib from

https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android/tree/master/Examples/google-play-services_lib

or

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/google-play-services

and now paste that in

E:\android\CFPEvents\cfp-android-user

now again import..

Comment: Sorry,This link has 404 page not found error..Please give another link

Comment: https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android/tree/master/Examples/google-play-services_lib

Comment: Ya..its ok ..but i still getting error ...after adding this jar file in libs folder and also installed google play service in sdk manager..Please help me

Answer (score 7):

find project.properties

open it,

delete（No package）android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
later,you need download the package.

link http://blog.csdn.net/wu_wxc/article/details/47091795

Comment: This is the proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the

```
 google_play_service_lib 
 in the folder
 E:\android\CFPEvents\cfp-android-user 
 and re-import the project.
```

Comment: You are importing an eclipse project?
It will be in the folder of the eclipse project work space.

Comment: No..I don't get that in project

Comment: You can find this in your android studio sdk folder if you've downloaded it from the SDK manger,
Path is C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject

Comment: You can download it from the SDK manger under the Extras Section -Google Play Service

Comment: Google play service is already installed in sdk...and I had added jar file in libs file but still getting error...Please help me..Thank you

Comment: You need to add the complete library project at location mentioned .Not the jar.
Copy the complete folder and paste it in the location mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are right but it seems it is only the First Step on the way to solving this issue because I had faced the same issue.

**So what can be done?**

**First Step**

- First download **google_service_libary** not only jar and now paste that in E:\android\CFPEvents\cfp-android-user(path of your project folder).

**Second Step**

- Close your project
- Back up your project
- Delete the **.idea folder** in the root directory of the project
- Delete all the **.iml files** in your project
- Import your project in Android Studio, and in the dialog that prompts
  you for a file, choose the build.gradle file.

After this you should be good to go.