# There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first "facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1"

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, android-studio, android-facebook

when I import Eclipse Project to android studio. I have a problem. I also refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123076/there-are-unrecoverable-errors-which-must-be-corrected-first) and I had download facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1 and add it in E:\graduation_thesis\Burglar project\Android but unsuccessful

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please paste the warnings you see on the first image.

Comment: open your `build.gradle` and in dependencies section add: `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.0.1'`

Comment: You should try and update to the latest SDK. Also note that , the Facebook SDK will not work eclipse. you should use android studio with it.