# "There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first" error when importing android project

Tags: android

I have a problem when I am trying to import an open source android project which I downloaded from the internet, so when I import it I passed some steps  but at last it stops processing and shows me this error :

"There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first" 
like the picture below .

anyone can help 
and thanks in advance .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30pPg.jpg)

Comment: [There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123076/there-are-unrecoverable-errors-which-must-be-corrected-first) the same question it will help you....

Comment: Thanks @ahdgfd , it works for me